# Writing to Excel CSV with a for loop using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas, for-loop

I have a list in Python

```
numbers_list = [(2,5), (3,4), (2,6), (3,5)...]
```

I want to copy the list to an Excel CSV called NumberPairings but I want each combination to be in a different row and each number in the row in different columns.

So I want the excel file to look like this:

```
 Num1  Num2
 2       5
 3       4
 2       6
 3       5
```

I think I should use a for loop that begins with
     for item in numbers_list:

But I need help with using Pandas to write to the file in the way I want it. If you think there is an easier way than Pandas, I'm open to it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the tuples into individual columns like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'tuples': numbers_list})
df
   tuples
0  (2, 5)
1  (3, 4)
2  (2, 6)
3  (3, 5)

df['Num1'] = df['tuples'].str[0]
df['Num2'] = df['tuples'].str[1]
df
   tuples  Num1  Num2
0  (2, 5)     2     5
1  (3, 4)     3     4
2  (2, 6)     2     6
3  (3, 5)     3     5

# optional create csv
df.drop(['tuples'], axis=1).to_csv(path)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And which method do you suggest to write it into the excel file row by row?

Comment: @memokerobi If you pass a valid path to `.to_csv()` it will output the entire dataframe. No need for loop.

Comment: I cannot use to_csv() with drop(). Do you know why is this the case?

Comment: It should work fine since `.drop()` returns a dataframe and `to_csv()` is a dataframe method. What's the error you're getting?